# How can i get the value outside foreach without using array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get `calleridnum` without using array . Is this possible?
or is there other way to do this ?

I have this code :

```
$participants = [
    [   'calleridnum' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay' 
    ],
    [   'calleridnum' => 2,
        'test' => 'yay' 
    ],
     [   'calleridnum' => 3,
        'test' => 'yay' 
    ]
];
$conferance_participants = [
    [   'uid' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay2',
        'dit' => 'deze'
    ],
    [  'uid' => 2,
        'test' => 'test',
        'dit' => 'wew'
    ]
];

foreach ($participants as $key=>$p) {
    foreach ($conferance_participants as $key=>$cp) {

        if ($p['calleridnum'] == $cp['uid']) {
                $calleridnum[]  =   $p['calleridnum'];

        } 

    } 
}

print_r( $calleridnum );
```

My output is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

but I want the output to be like this

```
1,2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `implode()` outside of `foreach loop`

```
 echo $str = implode (",", $calleridnum);
```

Comment: can i then check each value without using foreach like `if $calleridnum == 1` should be TRUE because the value is 1,2 ?

Comment: use `if (in_array("1", $calleridnum))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **`Implode`** your array to be converted into string.

```
  $calleridnum= [];

  foreach ($participants as $key=>$p) {
    foreach ($conferance_participants as $key=>$cp) {

     if ($p['calleridnum'] == $cp['uid']) {
            $calleridnum[]  =   $p['calleridnum'];

     } 

    } 
 }

$result = implode(',', $calleridnum);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Are you comparing the data in `$participants` and `$conferance_participants`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll simply use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php),[`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) along with [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as

```
echo implode(',', array_intersect(array_column($conferance_participants,'uid'), array_column($participants,'calleridnum')));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/427842)

Comment: can i then check each value without using foreach like `if  $calleridnum == 1` should be TRUE because the value is 1,2 ?

Comment: You can simply use `in_array` instead